# Desktop folder has changed overnight

Tags: macos, desktop

I turned off displaying files, folders, and volumes on my desktop. Now my desktop is clear and shows only my background image. I've been letting all apps that want to save to desktop do so. I've accumulated over 100 screenshots for example. My Desktop folder contained around 3 GB of files. This afternoon when I got on my computer I produced a screenshot. I went to open the screenshot in Preview and discovered my Desktop folder has been altered. There are still files there but all screenshots, for example, were missing along with several folders. When I go to the Desktop folder, I discover a new folder named "Desktop - name-of-my-computer". As I said, this new folder is inside my desktop folder. Inside this new folder there appear to be all items that were on my desktop yesterday. My question is does anyone know what happened to change my desktop folder?

Comment: Sounds like a side-effect of icloud drive. I've experienced similar behaviour with my Documents folder. Do you have multiple Macs that you login to?

Comment: Thanks, you are probably right.  No, I only have my 1 mac.

Comment: That happens when you turn off or turn on ( I don’t remember ) desktop and documents in iCloud Drive settings. Check in home folder a folder named iCloud archive or similar. You can cut paste the contents from there.

Comment: I don't have a folder by that name.  thank you though for replying.